# How to vectorise travelling salesman

Tags: python

I've been working on this TSP for a while and as soon as i get over 10 towns it takes forever. I need to vectorise but am not sure how to go about it. Below is what I have so far. (In python)
Thankyou

```
def travel_sale(coord):
    """ Solve the travelling salesman problem
    Assuming returning to home town

    Inputs:
    ------------
        coord = town coordinates with first row home town ([x,y])

    Outputs:
    ------------
        opt = optimum route
        dist = distance covered squared
        """
    m, n = np.shape(coord)
    # make the number of routes tested factorial m
    no = sci.factorial(m, exact=True)
    opt = np.nan
    dist = np.nan
    for i in range(0, no):
        r = np.random.uniform(0, 1, m)
        pr = np.argsort(r)
        # print(pr)
        path = np.vstack((coord[0, :], coord[pr, :], coord[0, :]))
        cost = np.sum(np.sqrt(np.sum(np.diff(path, axis=0)**2, axis=1)))
        if (i == 0):
            dist = cost
            opt = path
        elif(cost < dist):
            dist = cost
            opt = path

    return opt, dist
```

Comment: Why do you use the random function? If you're evaluating the whole solution space, then just iterate through it deterministically. Using the random function you are just running the risk of evaluating the same route twice

Comment: Vectorization won't make an `O(n!)` algorithm feasible. At best, it might increase the largest `n` you can run it on by 1 or 2.

Comment: I have an array of distances between each of the towns. I'm unsure how best to solve using that though for less computations